# Entity Framework Core DbContext set DbConnection

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework-core, dbcontext

In .NET Framework was DbContext in EntityFramework 6 was [constructor](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.dbcontext.dbcontext(v=vs.113).aspx) where I can set DbConnection.

In EF .NET Core can I set DbContext DbConnection? I hit an exception  in UseTransaction of DbContext method:

> An exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Relational.dll but was not handled in user code: 'The specified transaction is not associated with the current connection. Only transactions associated with the current connection may be used.'

Does any body know how set the DbConnection? Or I have get a wrong way?

Comment: You can set the connection string in OnConfiguring override method your DbContext. For more information.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/miscellaneous/connection-strings

Comment: See [Cross-context transaction](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/saving/transactions#cross-context-transaction-relational-databases-only) topic in the documentation. It covers your question and contains examples of [how to provide connection externally](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/saving/transactions#allow-connection-to-be-externally-provided).

Answer (score 0):

I have always added the Database Context within the startup file of .Net core apps by adding it to the IServiceCollection and pulling the string from the appsetting file like so:

```
        private void AddDatabase(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        var databaseConnectionString = Configuration.GetConnectionString("DatabseConnection");

        Check.CanConnectToDatabase(databaseConnectionString);

        services.AddDbContext<DatabaseContext>(
            options =>
            {
                options.ConfigureWarnings(
                    warnings => warnings.Throw(RelationalEventId.QueryClientEvaluationWarning));
                options.UseSqlServer(databaseConnectionString,
                    sqlOptions => sqlOptions.MigrationsHistoryTable(HistoryRepository.DefaultTableName, "SchemaName"));
            });
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you can not create `DbConnection` because it's a protected class hence you should get DbConnection then you set the connection string and finally set your DbCollection.

```
var dbConnection =  (await GetDbContextAsync()).Database.GetDbConnection();
dbConnection.ConnectionString = "yourConnectinString";
(await GetDbContextAsync()).Database.SetDbConnection(dbConnection);
//Also you can test your connection
await (await GetDbContextAsync()).Database.CanConnectAsync();
```

Maybe it's a tricky way but it worked for me.
Regards

Comment: Why? This is so convoluted. See the links in the comments. There are far easier ways to do this.

Comment: Because in run-time I have to check the connection string whether is correct or not.

Comment: I don't see how that demands this solution. But even so, a solution driven by a personal *extra* requirement doesn't answer the question. Also, "you can not create DbConnection" is not correct. You can create a brand-specific `DbConnection`, like `SqlConnection`.

Comment: I'm using that just for efcore (I need to implement it for mondo as well)
The user sends a connection string and I check it whether is valid or not.

If I follow your way, it will dependent mssql but my project supports different implementations. Hope it's clear to you.